# Is this an elliptic curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am trying to learn what elliptic curves are. Sofar 
I have not had any luck understanding when a curve is elliptic and when it is not.

Is this an elliptic curve?

$$y^2 = \frac{x}{4}-\frac{17 x^2}{40}+\frac{23 x^3}{90}-\frac{23 x^4}{360}+\frac{x^5}{180}$$

[image: elliptic curve or not]

The complete program in Mathematica:

```
Clear[nn, t, n, k, M, x];
nn = 6;(*size of matrix*)
Table[
 Clear[t, n, k, M, x];
 t[n_, 1] = 1;
 t[1, k_] = 1;
 t[n_, k_] := 
  t[n, k] = 
   If[n < k, 
    If[And[n > 1, k > 1], x - Sum[t[k - i, n], {i, 1, n - 1}], 0], 
    If[And[n > 1, k > 1], x - Sum[t[n - i, k], {i, 1, k - 1}], 0]];
 M = Table[Table[t[n, k]/n, {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
 (*MatrixForm[M]*)
 a = Det[M]; (*polynomial*)
 xy = 5;
 xmin = -5;
 xmax = 10;
 ymin = -1;
 ymax = 1;
 {nn, ContourPlot[y^2 == a, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}]}, {nn, 
  1, 24}]
(*Solve[Det[M]==0,x] (*solutions to the polynomial*)*)
```

Comment: I don't think it is. Loosely based on the definition of elliptic curves, highest power of the $x$ should be 3.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve

Comment: This has genus $2$, according to Maple, so it is not elliptic.

Comment: I don't understand what the connection is between the code and the question.

Comment: The polynomial is the 6-th polynomial in the code. The rest of the code is only there for my own memory.

Comment: By Harnack's curve theorem, the genus of the curve should be at least 2 — hence it is not an elliptic curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely *not* an elliptic curve: an equation $y^2=f(x)$ with $f$ having no repeated factors is "hyper-elliptic", giving an elliptic curve exactly when the degree of $f$ is $3$ or $4$. It is a curve of genus $g$ for $f$ of degree $2g+1$ and $2g+2$, generally, as one can see from the Riemann-Hurwitz formula, taking into account the points lying over $\infty$ on the Riemann sphere $\mathbb P^1\supset \mathbb C^1$.